# При переносе сайта с хостинга на локальный комп выдает ошибку?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_setting() in C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\stalnofftest\wp-content\themes\dt-the7\inc\mods\theme-update\theme-update.php on line 35

Comment: Видать, не всё перенёс... или версии файлов разбежались.

Comment: @Akina, есть ли какой нибудь более здоровый способ перенести сайт с хостинга? вроде добавил в архив, не знаю почему файлы разбежались

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)